# Dynamics CRM lookup to quote products (aka quote details)

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015, dynamics-crm-2016

I'm using CRM 2016 quotes and quote products (quote details). Business requirement is to have a possibility to specify requested delivery dates to each quote product. There might be several delivery dates to one quote product.
I want to create custom entity "delivery dates", that would have lookup to quote product.

Relationships should look like this:
Quote -- 1:N -->  Quote Products -- 1:N --> Delivery Dates

Unfortunately I cannot find Quote Products in Target lookup types. Is there a way to accomplish my desired outcome?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create 1:N relation from entity 'quote details' the only option is N:N and N:1.

Comment: Well I've figured that out... any ideas for a workaround?

Comment: Can't you go with N:N relation?

Comment: pen2, great suggestion. I've just checked it out. N:N would not work exactly as expected. I would have to override "add existing" buttons in order to make creation of records similar to 1:N relationship.

Comment: Or you could just create a plugin that fires on the association and will throw an error if there is already is an entity record associated.